# Fastest way to ceil any decimal number

Tags: javascript, math, ceil

I have two variables:

```
var elems;
var limit;
```

Both can be any random integer number.

So imagine that elems = 5 and limit = 3, and that elems / limit gives us a set of boxes.

If elems is a multiple of limit, then we will get only "full boxes", otherwise, `if limit < elems` we will get one extra "incomplete box". `If limit > elems`, then of course we only get "one full box".

For instance (5 / 3):

```
total elems: 5
limit: 3
offset:              0      3
box number:         [0]    [1]
elems contained:     3      2

offset = box number * limit
```

In this example, box offset 3 is the "incomplete box" and box offset 0 is the complete one.

**I want to find the maximum offset**, for any case where you are given any number of elements and any number for the limit. The problem, in its most simple form, is **finding the fastest method to ceil up ANY number that has ANY decimals in ANY place**, *in a way that it is adapted to fit the find max offset problem*.

So far I have come up with these solutions:

```
maxOffset = ((elems / limit - 1 | 0) + Math.ceil((elems % limit) / limit)) * limit; 

maxOffset = Math.abs(Math.ceil((elems / limit) - 1) * limit);

maxOffset = (elems === limit) ? 0 : (1 === limit) ? (elems - 1) : (elems / limit >> 0) * limit;
```

However, I'm looking for a more elegant solution. I was thinking maybe:

```
maxOffset = ((elems / limit) - 1E-16 | 0) * limit;
```

But I'm not sure what exactly would happen with huge numbers (I'm assuming it would fail?), and if 1E-16 is in fact the smallest decimal number any float can have.

This is not homework at all, I'm just a hobbyist programmer, and I'm trying to solve this problem for a CMS I'm writing. I hope I was clear, thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with using [*Math.ceil*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.6)? `| 0` effectively floors the value.

Comment: Nothing, I'm just trying to find the most fun way. :p Yeah, but the thing is adapting the whole thing to find the max offset. So for instance, if | 0 is used, then you have to add tests in case lim === lim or 1 === lim.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, nor how you calculate the offset. `Math.ceil(5/3)` is 2, where does 3 come from? A simple *ceil* function is: `function ceil(n) {return (n | 0) + (n%1? (n < 0? -1 : 1) : 0);}`, though that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, basically, I want to 'calculate' how many times limit fits in elems, regardless of whether it 'fits completely' or not. Math.ceil(5/3) indeed returns 2, and if you look at it in a way, that's how many times limit fits in elems. But offset must start at 0, hence why I substract -1 from that result, so I can later multiply it by the limit, to get the correct "biggest" offset. Math.ceil((elems / limit) - 1) * limit is the clearest example of doing so, and that's why it returns 3, when elems is 5. I can substitute the ceiling function you gave me for Math.ceil and test performance, thanks.

Comment: I expect *Math.ceil* to be faster as I've always found the conditional operator (`? :`) to be slower than the equivalent if..else loop, however it can be much more readable for simple expressions.

Comment: And I guess Math.stuff are also optimized in a way, correct? Yeah, I find the ? : operator to be pretty neat for stuff like that. Either way, I guess readibility isn't a problem for me, since I doubt my code will ever be read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example, you want

```
maxOffset = limit * Math.floor((elems - 1) / limit);
```

since that's the largest index for the *first* element of any box. Fo for `limit = 3`, you get `maxOffset == 0` for `elems` in {0, 1, 2}, `maxOffset == 1` for `elems` in {3, 4, 5} and so on. If your integers are non-negative, I might write this as

```
maxOffset = limit * (((elems - 1) / limit) | 0);
```

Lesson to learn: instead of subtracting some floating-point offset from the fraction, subtract an integral offset from the numerator instead and you can stay completely in integer arithmetic which the JS engine might be able to exploit for more performance.